# @ManyToMany in hibernate returns empty set in entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm developing some business application and created a many to many relationship between two entities. One of them is a super class but that is not what is causing the issue I think... The problem I faced is quite abysmal! I have for example two entities in database. One of them is AuditedEntity and another one is TaxonomyElement. I have also a table that holds relationship that was generated by hibernate and spring framework. In that table I have a relation between the two entities (table just holds a pair of two foreign keys).

When I fetch AuditedEntity - the taxonomyElements Set is an EMPTY SET!!! Even though the relation exists in database. More bizarre is the fact that if I change the Set to be a List (in any of the entities) then suddenly my TaxonomyElement is on that list (that was not easy to discover)!

Very puzzling... here is the code:

```
package com.app.domain.auditedEntity;

import com.app.domain.taxonomyElement.TaxonomyElement;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import java.util.*;

@Data
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class AuditedEntity {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
  @Column(length = 36)
  private String id;

  @Version
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer version;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "audited_entity_to_taxonomy_element",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "audited_entity_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "taxonomy_element_id")}
  )
  private final Set<TaxonomyElement> taxonomyElements = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
package com.app.domain.taxonomyElement;

import com.app.domain.auditedEntity.AuditedEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import java.util.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaxonomyElement {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
  @Column(length = 36)
  private String id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "taxonomyElements", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private final Set<AuditedEntity> auditedEntities = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I think this could be a bug in the framework or something very deep in it that is caused by something I'm totally unaware of. You should be able to replicate this even though I removed some fields from entities. I'm using Hibernate with JPA and getting the AuditedEntity with simple findById(id) call.

```
public interface AuditedEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<AuditedEntity, String> {}
```

Comment: Did you try to turn on the Hibernate property show-sql=true? Maybe the SQL  script will help to understand.

Comment: It's on and it's selecting the right table.

Comment: The problem is in Data annotation - it doesn't work correctly with JPA. Use Getter and Setter. More details here https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/